# Is there a way that we can trigger mouseover event on echarts library when hovering on any point of the series, rather than hover on a data point?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using echarts library for displaying line charts. I want to trigger **`mouseover`** events on any point of the series from the axis rather than hovering on the data-points. What configurations or options should I use? What kind of approach I can use for that?

The charts to display on the **`reactjs`** app. I have tried to set **`{trigger: "axis"}`** in the chart option but it always triggers event on the data point.

```
//chart option:

tooltip: {
            trigger: 'item',
            show: true
}

//callback for the event: 

onTooltipMouseOver = (e) => {
        let eventObj = e;
        console.log("{chk ==> ", eventObj)
}
```

The actual output is what I am expecting but I want it on hovering any point of the series from the axis

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the mouseover event can be triggered from anywhere on the chart.

However, you can use custom code for the tooltip formatter. The tooltip formatter function will be called when hovering anywhere on the chart:

```
tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    formatter: function (params) {

        // Get your data from params, eg: params[0].data

    }   
  }
```

One drawback of this approach is that you have to code the tooltip appearance. If you don't want the tooltip to show up, just make sure the custom formatter does not return any value.